# How to get pytorch all layers used in the forward function?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I want to get all the layers of the pytorch, there is also a question [PyTorch get all layers of model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846905/pytorch-get-all-layers-of-model) and all those methods iterate on the children or named_modules.

However when I tried to use it to get all the layers of resnet50, I found that in the source code of the BottleNeck in Resnet, there is only one relu layer. But this relu layer was used three times in the forward function.

All the methods I found can only parse one relu layer, which is not what I want. I am looking forward to a method that get all the layers sorted by its forward order.

```
    class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
# Bottleneck in torchvision places the stride for downsampling at 3x3 convolution(self.conv2)
# while original implementation places the stride at the first 1x1 convolution(self.conv1)
# according to "Deep residual learning for image recognition"https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385.
# This variant is also known as ResNet V1.5 and improves accuracy according to
# https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/model-scripts/nvidia:resnet_50_v1_5_for_pytorch.

expansion: int = 4

def __init__(
    self,
    inplanes: int,
    planes: int,
    stride: int = 1,
    downsample: Optional[nn.Module] = None,
    groups: int = 1,
    base_width: int = 64,
    dilation: int = 1,
    norm_layer: Optional[Callable[..., nn.Module]] = None,
) -> None:
    super().__init__()
    if norm_layer is None:
        norm_layer = nn.BatchNorm2d
    width = int(planes * (base_width / 64.0)) * groups
    # Both self.conv2 and self.downsample layers downsample the input when stride != 1
    self.conv1 = conv1x1(inplanes, width)
    self.bn1 = norm_layer(width)
    self.conv2 = conv3x3(width, width, stride, groups, dilation)
    self.bn2 = norm_layer(width)
    self.conv3 = conv1x1(width, planes * self.expansion)
    self.bn3 = norm_layer(planes * self.expansion)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.downsample = downsample
    self.stride = stride

def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    identity = x

    out = self.conv1(x)
    out = self.bn1(out)
    out = self.relu(out)

    out = self.conv2(out)
    out = self.bn2(out)
    out = self.relu(out)

    out = self.conv3(out)
    out = self.bn3(out)

    if self.downsample is not None:
        identity = self.downsample(x)

    out += identity
    out = self.relu(out)

    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

The relu isnt a layer, since it has no weights. But for the display of the architecture of a network check: [enter link description here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-do-you-visualize-neural-network-architectures)

Comment: thank you. but my point is that I want to get the execution order or all those nn.modules(or nn.function, include relu). But if user defined a layer once and used it for many times, like the example resnet code, It's hard to get the execution order of the model