# torchinfo summary show inner modules?

Tags: pytorch

I am using summary from torchinfo. My model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=1, nhead=1, dim_feedforward=1)
        self.trans = nn.TransformerEncoder(self.encoder_layer, num_layers=1)
    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.trans(x)
        return y
```

However, the output only gives me:

```
MyModel                                       [1, 1]                    16
├─TransformerEncoder: 1-1                     [1, 1]                    --
│    └─ModuleList: 2-1                        --                        --
│    │    └─TransformerEncoderLayer: 3-1      [1, 1]                    14
```

How do I go deeper and see the architecture of TransformerEncoderLayer using summary?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544742/11131433). Also try to set `depth` parameter of `torchinfo.summary` to a value bigger than default `3`.